# Completeness of $H_n(t)$

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm reading J. Michael Steele's [Stochastic Calculus and Financial Applications](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441928627), and a bit confused at a completeness statement.

At ch 3.3. *Two Wavelets*, it defines

$$H(t) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{for}\; 0\le t\le \frac12 \\ -1 & \text{for}\;  \frac12 \le t \le 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
, then for $n=2^j+k$, where $0\le k < 2^j$ and $j\ge 0$,
$$H_n(t) = 2^{j/2}H(2^jt-k)$$
, also set $H_0(t)=1$.

Then it states:

> ... to check completeness we note that — up to sets of measure zero —
> the  indicator function of any binary interval
> $[k \cdot 2^{-j}, (k +1) \cdot 2^{-1} ]$ is in the linear span  of the $\{H_n\}$.
> Since the linear combinations of such indicators can approximate any
> $f \in L^2[0, 1]$ as closely as we like, we conclude that the linear span of
> $\{H_n\}$ is dense.

I'm a bit confused here: $H_n$ is defined from $H(t)$, which is not $\mathbb 1_{[0,1]}(x)$ (the indicator function on $[0,1]$), how can  $\{H_n\}$ be complete?

Comment: Your logic is strange. Why do you think $(H_n)$ cannot be complete? Proofs are available easily and if you have difficulty in understanding some steps  you can seek help here.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think that's exactly the point of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter, but your definition of $H(t)$ is ambiguous for $t = \frac{1}{2}$.

Let's work with
$$
H = 1_{[0, \frac{1}{2})} -  1_{[\frac{1}{2}, 1]}.
$$ (it really doesn't matter whether the intervals include $\frac{1}{2}$ as we are working in $L^2$, that means only up to measure zero).

Let's also work with the notation
$$
H_{j, k}(t) = 2^{j/2} H(2^j t - k)
$$ instead of $H_n$ for simplicity.

The scale factor $2^{j/2}$ is irrelevant for the problem ($2^{-j/2}H_{j, k}$ is in the linear span too), so we drop it and redefine
$$
H_{j, k}(t) := H(2^j t - k) = 1_{[2^{-j}k, \,2^{-j} (k + \frac{1}{2}))} -  1_{[2^{-j}(k + \frac{1}{2}), \,2^{-j} (k + 1)]}.
$$

Now it looks a little bit more like the wanted indicator.
I drew a picture so you can convince yourself how the formulas have to be to get the indicator as a linear combination of $H_{j,k}$'s:
[image: (crappy)]